# Do we allow to ask Specific/Well Known Puzzle questions?

Tags: discussion

After reading [Posting a challenge, and answering it yourself](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/posting-a-challenge-and-answering-it-yourself) I get a feeling that asking specific known puzzle questions (ignoring the "Self-Answer" part) is not welcome.

I am curious to know, I know this is intended as a Q&A site (what's more Q&A than: what the answer for this XXXX puzzle....), and it will atract both Mathematics/Logic/Puzzle lovers/Experts/Educators/Researchers and plenty other more.

Both experts and layman will benefit from asking these specific questions.

Ignoring the fact that a well known question for one, might be a whole new puzzle for the other, I see no problem allowing such questions.

I don't think we will get questions like:

> Having a 1,000 Cubic Liter pool, with 3 hoses that can fill it in 5
>   hours. If only one hose will work, how long will it take to the pool
>   to fill up?

So I don't see a problem allowing puzzle questions.

Answer (score 1):

We've already got several meta discussions going on this topic right now.

[This meta question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/is-it-on-topic-to-present-specific-logic-puzzles-or-brainteasers-as-questions?cb=1) is the original, where we decided that posting specific puzzles was indeed on-topic.

Then we started getting an awful lot of them, without much variation from the original, and the community started discussing the "puzzle dump" problem (see [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/gathering-chestnuts?cb=1) meta post from an SE employee, Jon Ericson, discussing this issue and how we can solve it).

And then we have another [meta discussion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146/are-we-ready-for-public-beta) from Gilles, asking if we were ready for public beta or not given the puzzle dump problem (among other things). In response to this, public beta was delayed a little while, but as you know we ended up there eventually.

So this is an ongoing discussion in several places, and you might want to read those meta posts and add your two cents! :)