# Asking questions-puzzles you know the answer to

Tags: discussion

So what is your policy for the quesions-puzzles, where the author knows the answer and post them for others to have a pleasure for the puzzle?

Following the discussions and simplicity of questions itself I practically sure that following questions are good examples:

[Paying the Troll toll](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/626/paying-the-troll-toll)
[Writing numbers puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/619/writing-numbers-puzzle)
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/595/determine-which-switch-goes-to-the-light
[Pirates and gold coins](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/128/pirates-and-gold-coins)

Why I am asking:
1. According to:
[Posting a challenge, and answering it yourself](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/posting-a-challenge-and-answering-it-yourself)
it has sense to ask question and answer it. But those examples doesn't have self answers, so the following link doesn't answer whether those questions should be on site.
2. When I post a puzzle and do not give it an answer (in spoiler tag) in the question itself, there are downvotes because people believe the question can be answered objectively. Sometimes correctly, but when they are not correct It is impossible to prove without answer.
3. When I post a puzzle and DO give it an answer (in spoiler tag) I am questioned what answer do I expect from other people to such a question? This is a reasonable question.

**So I would like to make it clear:

1. Can users ask questions, which asks for a solution for a puzzle, they know the solution to?

2. If they can must they add the solution somewhere?

2.1. If they must where should it be? In the question itself (in spoiler tag)? As an usual answer to their own question? As an comment to the question?

3. Should they do something move special about such a questions? (for example, add a specific tag, or say "I know the solution").**

The "possible duplicate" [Posting a challenge, and answering it yourself](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/posting-a-challenge-and-answering-it-yourself) answers on the very first question (as "yes"?), but not on the rest 3.

Comment: There's nothing new in your question that wasn't considered in http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51/posting-a-challenge-and-answering-it-yourself. Besides, it's a non-issue: a question is valid or not based on what is written in it, not based on supplementary knowledge of the asker.

Comment: @Gilles, well I don't see answers to the given 4 questions there. Would you mind to summarise everything what was considered there here, and structure it according to my question lists?

Comment: FYI, I would rather you answer your questions as an answer than in the question.  SE does not frown against answering you own questions at the same time as asking it to either share your knowledge with the community or show how you view it so far.

Comment: IMO this question could be rephrased to make a great puzzle with interesting answers :D

Answer (score -1):

I think one can and must answer these question following Help centre article: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

**1. Can users ask questions, which asks for a solution for a puzzle, they know the solution to?**
Yes.
**2. If they can must they add the solution somewhere?**
There is no "must", but it is encouraged.
**2.1. If they must where should it be? In the question itself (in spoiler tag)? As an usual answer to their own question? As an comment to the question?**
In the usual answer to their own question.
**3. Should they do something move special about such a questions? (for example, add a specific tag, or say "I know the solution").**
Not really. To make an answer is enough, since it make the difference between such question and other self-obvious.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to do this. Not many go out of their way to understand the SE engine.