# When should I answer my own puzzle?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I was going to ask if I should ever answer my own puzzles, but conveniently there was already [such a question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6180/should-i-ever-reveal-the-solution-to-my-puzzle). So now my question becomes:

**When would it be wise to answer your own puzzle?**

As in, how long would one consider it as "long enough" before they decide that, if no one has answered correctly yet, you should do it yourself? I don't want to answer too quickly as to give people a chance to try, but I'd like the puzzle to have the correct answer, so future users who stumble upon it don't have to feel like they'll never know.

Comment: If you do decide to answer your own post, consider using the wrap-up template (search for wrap on meta). There's usually a lot to be learned when a question doesn't get answered and it would be great to have that along with the solution.

Comment: Good answer to this here and another good answer see https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/how-long-should-i-wait-before-providing-the-answer-to-my-riddle, which ithink is pretty much a duplicate, so maybe this one should be reviewed.... Anyway answer here and answer there are both useful,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how long would one consider it as "long enough"

That's going to depend a lot on individual opinion. Definitely not on the scale of hours or days, though - maybe not even weeks, more like months. [This riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5019/5373) lasted three weeks before being solved, and [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15187/5373) lasted almost a month despite increasing numbers of hints. **You never know when some genius might show up out of nowhere with an insight that nobody else saw.** I suggest leaving it a *loooong* time before you start to consider self-answering your own puzzle. Instead, add hints (and more hints, and more hints) or place bounties. It'll be far more satisfying - both for you *and* the solver - if someone else manages to solve it than if you just post the answer yourself.