# How to add hints to cipher questions?

Tags: discussion

I have a [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115720/running-away-from-a-5-euro-fine) on puzzling.se. I have posted a couple of hints and I can't give any more hints without giving the answer because the cipher is pretty simple. I even set a bounty and there is very little feedback. Should I answer my own question or is there an additional step I can do to get people to answer my question? I followed the things recommended by this [meta answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2800/78801) and this [meta answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6366/78801).

Comment: My general suggestion - probably not quite enough for an answer - is 'don't worry so much about it'. Let it lie for a while. Many problems posed on this site don't get answered for many days, weeks, months or even [years](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/59690/60644)! Sometimes it just needs the right person with the right insight to come along and have that 'aha' moment that lets them solve it. Specifically, for your puzzle, I would say the second hint is VERY vague - if you're looking for an area to drop another hint, consider pointing people directly to the relevant part of the e-mail.

Comment: @Stiv the 2nd hint is about the mail as a whole