# Can we self-answer our questions if no one answers? Should we?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I know that self-answering is generally encouraged on SE. However, I thought Puzzling.SE might be a bit of an exception; by and large (although not always) askers already know the answer. So can we self-answer, if we want to show the solution to our puzzle? If so, under what conditions should we?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long should I wait before providing the answer to my riddle?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/how-long-should-i-wait-before-providing-the-answer-to-my-riddle)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What usually happens is that puzzle authors give hints; first, simple nudges, but I've seen hints which spoil half the puzzle, so to speak. Depending on the type of puzzle, posting a simplified version which introduces techniques to solve the main puzzle may work. Also, a [bounty](/help/bounty) may help getting more attention to your puzzle too.

Sometimes it's difficult to give hints without spoiling the puzzle entirely. I guess in that case you *could* self-answer it eventually, but only if the solution has any value by itself. What I mean by this is that the value of e.g. a [connect-wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connect-wall) lies in *solving* it, while a clever [geometry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) proof may have some value if it isn't posed as a puzzle.

Finally, we have [many](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) unsolved puzzles here, and while it can be frustrating as a puzzle-maker that your challenge isn't solved, one day a new puzzler might successfully pick up your challenge (or a veteran may have a second look and a moment of brilliance). If you're specifically thinking of [your latest puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/98949/11110), it's only a week old; some users might be on vacation or otherwise not visiting Puzzling Stack Exchange for that long.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for your help! Your point about geometry as opposed to connect-wall is a well-made one.